# wkid error using buffer GeometryService - ArcGIS JS API 3.2

Tags: buffer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

First of all, going to this [url](https://utility.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer) for the geometry service referenced in the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#buffer) shows it's been deactivated so I instead chose this [url](http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/buffer?geometries=&inSR=&outSR=&bufferSR=&distances=&unit=&unionResults=true&geodesic=false&f=html) - both with /GeometryServer and /GeometryServer/buffer.

I suspect it has something to do with the spatial reference of my geometry or buffer param but I've used different GCS and PCS with the same result.

```
require(["esri/map",
     "esri/SpatialReference",
     "esri/geometry/Point",
     "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
     "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
     "esri/graphic",
     "esri/Color",
     "esri/tasks/BufferParameters",
     "esri/tasks/GeometryService"], 
function(Map, SpatialReference, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Graphic, Color, BufferParameters, GeometryService) {
var map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "streets",
    center: [-97.744483, 30.272705], 
    zoom: 15
});
//Locate By Lat/Long
document.getElementById("btnLocate").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var latitude = Number(document.getElementById("latitude").value);
    var longitude = Number(document.getElementById("longitude").value);
    var pointGCS = new esri.geometry.Point(longitude, latitude, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 }));
        var pointWMS = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(pointGCS);
        var crossHair = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CROSS, 12, 
            new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new Color([255, 0, 0]));
        var centerpoint = new Graphic(pointWMS, crossHair);
//Set buffer parameters
    var params = new BufferParameters();
    params.bufferSpatialReference = new SpatialReference({ wkid: 32662 });
    params.outSpatialReference = new SpatialReference({ wkid: 32662 });
    params.unit = GeometryService.UNIT_STATUTE_MILE;
    params.distances = [0.25, 0.50, 1];
    params.geometries = [centerpoint];
    var geoService = new GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
    geoService.buffer(params);
    map.centerAndZoom(pointWMS, 15);
    }); 
});
```

[image: Error:]

Comment: can you please clarify which line in your code snippet above causes that error? Is it `geoService.buffer(params)`?

Comment: It is the line: geoService.buffer(params);

Comment: can you put a breakpoint in your developer tools on that line, print the values of `params` at that point (including expanding all of the > arrows to show their component values), and add as a screenshot? Something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/jWjBaHp.png)

Comment: 32662 isn't a valid WKID. What coordinate system are you trying to use?

Comment: I was originally using 4236 but the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/bufferparameters-amd.html#bufferspatialreference) used 32662 so I tried that. However I do see now that it's been [deprecated](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-plate-carree/), but using any wkid for the buffer params gives me the same result.

Comment: @StephenLead [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/375291/2534669/kb0qIELEUKpDuxk/upload.png) is the screenshot of the params object